# GAE go user logout strange behavior

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, go

I have no idea why the first function works perfectly and the second function never logs out and I am always logged in. The structure defined corresponds to a templates variable.

MOST strange thing is that in the two different handlers the call to LogoutURL generates two different links (not only the return URL the structure of those two are different one[index page's one which works] starts with myapp-notworking-000.appspot.com and then _ah/logout URL and the admin pages one starts with https://google.com/accounts and all). What am I missing here? Why is GAE so complicated??

```
import (
    "appengine"
    "appengine/user"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("static/tmpl/*"))

type AdminPage struct {
    Admin_email string
    LogoutUrl   string
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Index)
    http.HandleFunc("/admin", Admin)
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    u := user.Current(c)
    if u == nil {
        url, _ := user.LoginURL(c, "/")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, `<a href="%s">Sign in or register</a>`, url)
        return
    }
    url, _ := user.LogoutURL(c, "/")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, `Welcome, %s! (<a href="%s">sign out</a>)`, u, url)
}

func Admin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    u := user.Current(c)
    an := AdminPage{"", ""}
    var templ = ""

    if u == nil {
        url, err := user.LoginURL(c, r.URL.String())
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        w.Header().Set("Location", url)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
        return
    }
    c.Debugf("User present %v", u)
    an.Admin_email = u.Email
    templ = "adminIndex"
    url, err := user.LoginURL(c, "/admin")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    an.LogoutUrl = url
    err = templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, templ, an)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

app.yaml file -----

```
application: myapp-notworking-000
version: beta
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  application_readable: true

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
  application_readable: true

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
  application_readable: true

- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  application_readable: true

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: static/fonts
  application_readable: true

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Comment: You're calling user.LoginURL() for both logged-in and logged-out users.

Comment: Such a stupidity!! Thanks for pointing that out. I can not believe this. Thanks a lot :)